# How does Symfony know where to find the services.yml config file?

Tags: symfony

In Symfony 3.0 (and I'm sure 2.X as well), if I want to make a custom constraint validator with a dependency, I have to register that validator as a service in the dependency injection container (which is described by default in project_directory/app/config/services.yml) using a special tag ( as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies)).

This means that the Validator component must know where to look for the service container. This issue also comes up for the ControllerResolver. Since controllers can be registered as services, the ControllerResolver must know where the service container is.

**How do the Symfony components know where to look for the service container, and how can I configure this?** I ask because I want to build a custom framework using the Symfony components, which means I'll be making my own service container, and I'd like to be able to point the Validator and the ControllerResolver to that service container.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony Standard Edition, the container is initialised by the Kernel. Have a look at the [`AppKernel`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f5b1ae88c3d2338f43a18363811f03bae196ff54/app/AppKernel.php) and its parent class.

The kernel loads a configuration file in [the `registerContainerConfiguration()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f5b1ae88c3d2338f43a18363811f03bae196ff54/app/AppKernel.php#L48):

```php
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

This code will load an environment specific configuration file (`config_prod.yml`, `config_dev.yml` etc). In a standard setup that file [imports the main `config.yml` file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f5b1ae88c3d2338f43a18363811f03bae196ff54/app/config/config_dev.yml#L2).

The `services.yml` file is [loaded with an import in `config.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f5b1ae88c3d2338f43a18363811f03bae196ff54/app/config/config.yml#L4):

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
```

If you're thinking of building your own framework (which is a good learning experience), you'll need to read more code of existing frameworks first. Also, it's worth to read the excellent [Create your own PHP framework](http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html).

> This means that the Validator component must know where to look for the service container

This is scary. I see no connection between validation and the service container. I'd think of a better design.

P.S. Everyone should write their own framework once. The next step should be deleting it.